# How can I know what model is my laptop display is?

Tags: laptop-display

I am not sure if this question belongs in this forum. If not, please guide me so that I will know where to post any follow up questions.

Question: I have an old laptop from several years ago that I would like to salvage. So, I saw a YT tutorial on how to use an old laptop's screen as an extended monitor. I disassembled the laptop screen as shown on the video clip and the next thing in order is to use a controller card (?). As soon as flipped the display, I saw a bunch of bar codes and I didn't know where to start. Below is the picture of the display and if someone could tell me what model it is, so that I could find the corresponding controller on ebay, that'd be brilliant.

Here is the picture of the back of my monitor:

[image: The back of the monitor]

p.s: Let me know if the picture is not expandable to view the bar codes. Right now, it is not letting me post anything beyond 2MB.

Comment: The name on the screen (Chunghwa) comes up in Google (eBay) and I expect the 3 numbers below are the model numbers of the screen

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I will look it up, but just quickly, when you say three numbers below ... you mean one of these three -- "CLAA154..." or "SG5K8 ..." or "74435 ..." ?

Comment: Yes. those are three number. Since the screen is not a separate part - just  screen for another assembly, I am not sure how to interpret them for external use and did not see any information about this.

Comment: So, does any controller board work with it?

Comment: There is no practical way to know that. The screen was matched to the laptop it was in and surrounding circuits between board and screen may have been needed to adapt the screen. No way to know

Comment: Bummer. Thanks though. Funny, how these DIY videos make it look like everything is so simple :/

Comment: You might find an inexpensive monitor that provides better resolution, though the laptop would be a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

[This screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003TP8NMK) exactly matches the part number from your photo. Does it also match your unit's dimensions and look? If yes, you can assume that the specified part number is probably correct.

There is [an eBay offer](https://www.ebay.de/itm/TV56-LCD-display-controller-kit-for-CLAA154WB08A-15-4-1280-800-CCFL-LVDS-30-pin-/173887435910) for a controller that apparently works with your panel (exactly matches the part number and photo). The description also has some more information. It seems that these LCD controller boards often work with a variety of panels.

Edit: I had another look at the eBay description - it seems that this seller sells one board and then flashes ("burns" as he says) the matching firmware for the panel that gets ordered. You should probably ask the seller if he has the right board and firmware on stock before ordering.